# How to pass data to angular async function from ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am trying to use an async function inside a service (so I can acces it from many controllers) and fill an array when I click on an element on the page.

As it is now, the async function will load right after page load. Here is the function ;

```
   routesApp.factory('angRoutes', function($http) {
    var angRoutes = {
      async: function() {    <----------- How to call this function with params

        var data = $.param({
            query: 'top'         <------------------- HOW TO PASS SOMETHING HERE

        });                         <-- I need to use ng-click="update('top')"

        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
            }
        }

        var promise =   $http.post('../ajax-php.php', data, config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            $('#ajaxLoader').hide(); /// hiding the loading gif

            return data;

       })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            return data = "Data: " + data +
                "<hr />status: " + status +
               "<hr />headers: " + header +
                "<hr />config: " + config;

        });
        return promise;
      }
    };
    return angRoutes;
  });
```

And the controller ;

```
  routesApp.controller('topRoutesCtrl', function topRoutesCtrl($scope,$http, angRoutes) {
    angRoutes.async().then(function(data) {
        $scope.angRoutes = data;
        console.log(data);
      }); 
});
```

I want to update my `$scope.angRoutes` using the same kind of async function but I need to pass data to the function. For Exemple ;

```
  <div ng-controller="navRoutesCtrl" class="c prise">c
        <img ng-click="update()" data-query="top" class= "priseimg" src="../images/prises/c-s.png"> 
     <div class="arrow-all arrow-c">
          TOP ROUTES
       </div>
    </div>
```

I use to do it with jquery and I would get the query param for the post from de data-query attribute.

Now I want to turn this into ;

```
 <div ng-controller="navRoutesCtrl" class="c prise">
  <img ng-click="update('top')" class= "priseimg" src="../images/prises/c-s.png"> 
  <div class="arrow-all arrow-c">
              TOP ROUTES
           </div>
        </div>
```

How do I change my service async function and set the .post query to what ever I pass to the update('query').

How do I need to rewrite the function so I can use it with ng-click

I want the exact same thing to happens but from a diffrent controller and a controller that will call the async function with a diffrent query.

Basically I need to call for an async $http function (result come from database and are sent as Json) from a ng-click with at least one param for the query.